What is needed to see "Databound columns" for DataSource in "Add Column" dialog for DataGridView
I am binding a DataGridView to a BindingList<Thing> by setting the DataSource property in the constructor of the form.
InitializeComponent();  
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = thingsList;

Thing is defined as:
public class Thing
{
public Prop1 { get; set; }
public Prop2 { get; set; }
}

I would like to be able to select the properties of Thing class from the "Databound columns" list in the DataGridView editor.

What is required for the Add Column dialog to display the properties of the type I am binding to?

AFAIR you need a proper data source, like DataTable. I guess you just need column names.

As for column type, order, visbility. etc. check other topics, e.g. this one.

You are right, it is possible to use visual designer to assign the name of the property that is databound to a column.
However, this has the disadvantage that the name of the property will be a string. If later you decide to change the name of the property, than the compiler can't check if you forgot to change the databound item as well.
It is way better assign this using nameof(...) in the constructor of your form. Use the visual studio designer to add the DataGridViewColumn, and assign the display format of a value, but what property should be displayed in the column can be done in the constructor.
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();  // creates the columns

    // define which column should show the value of which property:
    this.columnProp1 = nameof(Thing.Prop1);
    this.columnProp2 = nameof(Thing.Prop2);
}

Now if later you decide to give your class and your properties proper identifiers, for instance class Product, properties Name and Price your compiler will complain if you forgot to update the constructor.
Other useful changes in your form class:
BindingList<Thing> DisplayedThings
{
    get => (BindingList<Thing>) this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

To get the Thing displayed in the currently selected row:
Thing CurrentThing => (Thing)(this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem);

And if the operator can select several rows:
IEnumerable<Thing> SelectedThings => this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<Thing>();

Usage:
IEnumerable<Thing> GetThingsToDisplay() { TODO: implement }

On showing the form for the first time, fill the DataGridView:
void OnForm_Load(object sender, ...)
{
    this.DisplayedThings = new BindingList<Thing>(this.GetThingsToDisplay().ToList());
}

If the operator can edit displayed Things: Add rows, remove rows, edit cells, he can press Apply Now when finished:
OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<Thing> editedThings = this.DisplayedThings;
    ICollection<Thing> originalThings = this.GetOriginalDisplayedThings() // TODO: implement

    // use LINQ to find out which rows are added / removed / changed
}
    
    

